# Explained variance in logistic regression based on regression coefficients

Tags: regression, logistic, variance, nonlinear-regression, r-squared

I am wondering about the relation between the explained variance and the regression coefficients in logistic regression. So given a multiple linear regression

$y_i = \beta_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{K} \beta_k x_{ki} + e_i$,

I know that $R^2$ can be simplified to

$ R^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \beta^2_k + 2 \sum_{k<k'}^{} \beta_k \beta_{k'} \rho_{kk'}$.

So given that we now the values of the regression coefficients and their interrelation $\rho_{kk'}$ we can determine $R^2$ for the linear case. Is there an equivalent in logistic regression? How would it work?

Comment: Since in logistic regression, most R2 meaures are a function of the full model's likelihood and an intercept model's likelihood, I guess it is about the relation between the regression coefficients and these two likelihood functions...

Comment: Do you have a reference for that formula for R-squared?

Comment: That formula for $R^2$ cannot be correct.  It depends on the scale of the variables, and it’s not even bounded above.

Answer (score 4):

The best basis for explained variation in binary Y is the variance of predicted probabilities.  This and related measures are discussed [here](http://fharrell.com/post/addvalue) which references important articles by Kent & O'Quigley and Choodari-Oskooei et al.

It doesn't help very much to expand the formula as you did, but the analogy to ordinary linear models is very helpful.  Think of partitioning sum of squares total into sum of squares regression and sum of squared errors: SST = SSR + SSE.  $R^2$ is essentially var(predictions) / var(raw Y).  var(predictions) is easy, and for non-ordinary linear models we have to work on var(raw Y) as Kent & O'Quigley did.  The blog article goes more into this.